# Why can't we observe colours in thick film interference?

Tags: interference

Please help!

Please keep the level at an introductory class level. Basic idea of coherence etc.
Can't understand Quantum physics etc.

Comment: Also [Why do thin films need to be thin?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/264082/why-do-thin-films-need-to-be-thin)

Answer (score 0):

When the film is many wavelengths in thickness, a small change in wavelength can make a big change in the amplitude. So, maybe 740 nm is suppressed but 750 nm is enhanced, but they both look red, so you don't perceive a color change. Your eyes don't have the spectral resolution.

Suppose the film is 1/2 wavelength in thickness, leading to constructive interference. You need to change the wavelength by 50% to reach fully destructive interference at 1/4 or 3/4 of a wavelength. Your eyes can easily perceive this difference in wavelength. But if the film is 25 wavelengths thick, the wavelength only has to change by 1% to reach 24+3/4 or 25+1/4 waves per film thickness. Your eyes cannot perceive such a slight change. Change the wavelength by 2%, and you get back constructive interference.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand. How does a change in wavelength relate to a change in amplitude?  Also, my specific question would be, why does all light constructively interfere and we get white light when the film is thick?

Comment: @User1233 When you see red from thin-film interference, that means that the interference has enhanced red wavelenghts and suppressed other wavelengths.

Comment: @User1233 It doesn't all constructively interfere, but your eyes' spectral resolution isn't good enough to distinguish between wavelengths where it constructively interferes and wavelengths where it destructively interferes.

Comment: So we get smeared white light? Fringes aren't easily distinguishable? My doubt is what does increasing thickness do exactly to path difference or coherence that leads to a smeared interference pattern?

Comment: @User1233 Not smeared. If you look at it with a spectrograph you see rapidly varying interference with wavelength.